# Dynamic listview adapter with arrow button

Tags: android

I have a `JSON` URL that contains title and images. I want to retrieve all title and images and put them into the dynamic `ListView` adapter with arrow button like the following `Google TV` play store. Any ideas on how to do this?

[image]

<<< Title1 >>>

```
 image1 - image 2 - image 3 - image 4 - image 5  arrow <<button>>
```

<<< Title2 >>>

```
 image1 - image 2 - image 3 - image 4 - image 5  arrow <<button>>
```

Comment: Use a Grid View and an Array Adapter, and download the data in a separate AsyncTask.